# Django can't find any views but index

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm pretty new to Python and Django as well, but I'm going through the tutorial as closely as I can and I must be missing something.  I can get my default index view to load, but I want to send an ajax call to a view called 'search' and I have another view called 'show' that would take an integer (show_id) and I get 404s on both of the calls to those pages.

What am I missing?  Do I need anything else in my settings?  My index view works fine, but these other routes aren't jiving.  Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:
Here is a screengrab of my folder structure: [image]

mediamanager/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mediamanager.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^manager', include('manager.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

Settings:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'manager'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mediamanager.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mediamanager.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

manager.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from manager import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<show_id>\d+)/$', views.show, name='show'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search')
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from manager.models import Show, Episode
import urllib2


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {'shows' : Show.objects.all().order_by('show_name')}
    return render(request, 'manager/index.html', context)


def show(request, show_id):
    s = Show.objects.get(show_id).order_by('-air_date')
    context = {'show': s, 'episodes': s.episodes}
    return render(request, 'manager/show.html', context)

def search(request):
    search_term = request.GET['show_search']
    search_results = urllib2.urlopen("http://thetvdb.com/3BBD3F7E1043129C/GetSeries.php?seriesname=%s" % search_term)
    return HttpResponse(search_results)
```

Comment: I'm thinking it may be something in your settings. The urls.py file, it's in the same folder as your views? Can you show your settings options here? You may need to explicitly route to the urls.py...

Comment: Expanding on the comment about, the filename `manager.urls.py` isn't standard - Django looks for `urls.py` by default.

Comment: @ZAR, the file name is urls.py.  I just added a screenshot of my file structure and that file.  Furthermore, wouldn't my index view have problems as well if that was the case?

Comment: In settings, what do you have under "ROOT_URLCONF = 'PROJECTNAME.urls'? As for your index question, there may be a default index that's showing up. It might not be linking to your set urls.py.. maybe.. it's a guess

Comment: @ZAR it is in the update - ROOT_URLCONF = 'mediamanager.urls'

Comment: you showed here that the file name is manager.urls.py:. your settings are mediamanager.py?

Comment: what is the full url you are requesting that is 404'ing?

Comment: The full URL that isn't jiving is /manager/search

Comment: My settings file is settings.py under the mediamanager directory.  The mediamanager/urls.py file points at the manager/urls.py file just like the Django tutorial does for the samples /polls/ app

Comment: A separate comment regarding your file structure. I'm looking at your file hierarchy, Do you have duplicate names? Mediamanager>Manager>Manager & Mediamanager>Manager>Mediamanager?

Comment: Yeah, i guess I do have duplicate names.  I used the Django 'startproject' command as detailed in the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

Comment: Right, I remember going through that tutorial. The tutorial worked for me, without issue. I wonder if your file structure, especially with the duplicate names is causing the error? Again, a guess.

Comment: @ZAR, thanks for all the details.  But that tutorial has a mysite/mysite directory, which is the same structure as mine.  Also, i'm still mystified by the fact that my index URL works just fine, but not the other two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
url(r'^manager', include('manager.urls')),
```

should be

```
url(r'^manager/', include('manager.urls')),
#             ^ The missing /
```

Now, the reason `index` works is, there is a pattern that matches `/manager`

Note that: `manager123/` (#where 123 is the show id) or `managersearch/`

would be valid URLs (non-404) in your application.

Comment: THANKS!  I knew it was something small I was missing!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url(r'^manager/', include('manager.urls')),
```

This should work